# Node JS dynamic collection ajax calls async wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to build a web scraper using node js. I have an array, which will have dynamic size. that array consists of list of URL to which I need to visit to.  I used https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js for web scraping. I'm creating request's using Request module for node js. I refereed this http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice , I guess async.forEach should be useful for my scenario but I'm not able to understand how do I make the API wait till all results of web scraping not acquired. I'm new to node js. Any guidance for this will be really helpful for me to move ahead.

okay. I'm adding some kind of code which I'm trying but not working the way I want.
I want all outputs of Async methods concatenated in some array as list of objects and send that to client as JSON.

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();
var async = require('async');
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
    
    //URL list will be dynamic.
    var urlList = ['1','2','3'];

//async for each
async.forEach(urlList,function(url,callback){
    
    
    request({url: url,
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'spider'
    }
    }, function(error, response, html){
        debugger;
        if(!error){
         debugger;
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            
            
            $('span').filter(function(){
                debugger;
                var data = $(this);
                //console.log(data)
                var someprocessedValue = data.attr('data');
                //release = data.children().last().children().text();
                callback(someprocessedValue);
            })
           
        }
        
    });
    
    
    
    
},
function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    res.send('Check your console!');
});

});
```

As per answer by @Robrich I have modified the code and got to a place where it is working. I'm posting code for reference if anyone wants to use it later.

```js
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res)
{
var urlList=['http://a.com','http://b.com'];


async.map(urlList,scrapper,function(err,results){
    if(err){
        
    }
    else
    {
        res.send('Check your console!');
    }
});
}
var scraper = function(url,cb){
var data = new Object();
data.url = url;
data.isError = false;
  request({url: url,
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'spider'
    }
    }, function(error, response, html){
        //debugger;
        if(!error){
         //debugger;
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    
            //some logic
            
            return cb(null,data);
        }
        else{
            data.IsError=true;
         return cb(error,data);
        }
        
    });
}
```

My code above might have brace issues. but I got it working the way I wanted.
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried async.parallel? (https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

Comment: actually I have a collection from which i need to create async's dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) instead of `async.forEach`

Comment: I have dynamic collection. So number of url can vary Everytime. How do I create those many number of requests on the fly and wait for the Request Complete and then process data. And finally return a new array full of results from all executions using what you suggested. I'm not able to understand. Can you provide some code example.